# Show that $gcd(x,y)$ and $z = lcm(x,y)$ is primitive recursive

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computability, recursive-algorithms

For the $gcd(x,y)$ we note:

$gcd(x,0) = x$

$gcd(x,succ(y)) = gcd(succ(y),mod(x,succ(y)))$

$succ(x)$ and $mod(x,y)$ are both primitive recursive, so $gcd(x,y)$ must be as well.

$z = lcm(x,y)$ if $x|z$ and $y|z$ and when $x|w$ and $y|w$, $z \leq w$. Show that $z = lcm(x,y)$ is primitive recursive.

Can we define $lcm(x,y)$ the same way $gcd$ is defined above? I feel that there should be some way to incorporate the two together (such that $lcm$ depends on $gcd$). How can we show that $lcm$ is primitive recursive?

Comment: If you can code your function using only _bounded_ loops, then it is primitive recursive. In this case, the result of $\gcd$ is bounded by both $x$ and $y$, while the result of $\mathrm{lcm}$ is bounded by $x*y$.

Comment: Interesting thought. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:
$$\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = \frac{xy}{\gcd(x,y)}?$$

Comment: Does this require that divides is primitive recursive as well?

Comment: It does, and it is. I thought you already have that as a fact since you have $mod$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you for your help!